# $\omega$ is cyclic for $M\subset B(H)$ if and only if $\omega$ is separating for $M'$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $M\subset B(H)$ a von Neumann algebra and $\omega \in H$ a vector. Then $\omega$ is cyclic for $M$ if and only if $\omega$ is separating for $M'$.

I proved "$\implies$". As for the other implication, we're trying to show that $M\omega$ is dense in $H$ given that $\omega$ is separating for $M'$. Let $P$ denote the projection onto the subspace $\overline{M\omega}$. We have that $(I-P)\omega=0$, so if we could show that $(I-P)\in M'$, then separability would imply that $I-P=0$, i.e. $I=P$. In particular, we would have $\overline{M\omega}=H$.

Is it true that $(I-P)\in M'$? I haven't been able to show it.

I am thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X\in M $. Then, for any $Y\in M $ you have $XY\omega\in M\omega $. So $XP=PXP $. If you do this for $X $ selfadjoint and take adjoints on the equality, you get  $XP=PX $. As selfadjoints span $M $, you get that  $P\in M'$.

Comment: Clever -- I learned a new trick. Thank you.

Comment: This is indeed clever. It is as old as von Neumann himself,  as far as I know.